# Compile error when calling std::from_chars with a double in libc++

Tags: c++, libc++

I have a small code as follows:

```
int main() {
    double d;
    const char* str = "26.50";
    std::from_chars(str, str + strlen(str), d);
    std::cout << d;
}
```

This code works as expected with libstdc++, but it fails with the following error in libc++ 12.0.0:

```
candidate template ignored: requirement '__or_<std::__or_<std::is_same<double, signed char>, std::is_same<double, short>, std::is_same<double, int>, std::is_same<double, long>, std::is_same<double, long long>>, std::__or_<std::is_same<double, unsigned char>, std::is_same<double, unsigned short>, std::is_same<double, unsigned int>, std::is_same<double, unsigned long>, std::is_same<double, unsigned long long>>, std::is_same<char, double>>::value' was not satisfied [with _Tp = double]
```

Is this a libc++ bug? or am I missing something? I should say that this code works if I change data type from `double` to `int`.

Comment: I don't think they have implemented floating point support yet.  Let me try and find the dupe target.

Comment: Yep, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support confirms that.

Comment: This is the best I'm finding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57825432/what-blocks-implementation-of-stdto-chars-and-stdfrom-chars

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ouch. I didn't think they may have implemented main but not specializations... <.< Ty info.

Comment: do you mean clang or libc++? Clang [compiles your code without errors](https://godbolt.org/z/o4fobjW7v)

Comment: @AlanBirtles: With libc++: https://godbolt.org/z/8nhM3Y3na

Comment: @BillLynch, yes that was my point, the problem is libc++ not clang as originally stated in the question